# If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^2(a_n)^2=5$, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the limit given is equal to 5, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2(a_n)^2$ diverges. Also, the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ converges through limit comparison test. But I don't know how to tie that in with  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.

Comment: $n^2 a_n^2 \to 5$ means that $|a_n| \sim \frac{\sqrt{5}}{n}$ for large $n$. Now try to come up with a concrete $a_n$ which has the given limit and where the series converges and one where the series diverges. The first one should be easy. For the second one try to make an *alternating series*

Comment: @Winther so are you saying that depending on the value of $a_n$, the series either converges or diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may converge Or diverge. To see this consider the following two cases:

$${{a}_{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{n}$$   $${{a}_{n}}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{n}}\frac{\sqrt{5}}{n}$$